# Correct way to link sheet names and XML files

Tags: excel, openxml

I've inherited a spreadsheet module that reads *.xlsx files with XML functions. The app maps data using sheet names and that part of the module is pretty broken.

I don't have a month to find and read the specs of the Office Open XML format so I've composed a quick hack after a quick look to some samples files:

1. Open `xl/workbook.xml` and loop `/workbook/sheets`:

   - Grab names from `name`.
   - Grab IDs from `r:id`.
   - Use file order as display order.
2. Open `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels` and loop `/Relationships` filtering by `Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet`:

   - Map to name through `Id`.
   - Map to file through `Target`.

Is this algorithm correct?

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are trying to do.  "The app maps data using sheet names" doesn't say very much.  What data are you trying to map, and what do you mean by map?  What are you looking for in the relationships

Comment: @Flydog57 The module reads data from an Excel spreadsheet. User uploads a document with two sheets labelled "Sales" (where cell "A1" is `29.95`) and "Purchases" (where cell "A1" is `13.50`). The code I've inherited often mixes that up: `29.95` gets randomly assigned to "Sales" or "Purchases". I've rewriting the specific part of the code that determines what XML file contains data for "Sales" and what file contains data for "Purchases". I hope this description makes more sense; otherwise, feel free to ask.

Comment: What I would do is open one of the spreadsheets in the OpenXml Productivity Tool (downloadable), look at where the data is, and use code to fetch the data I was looking for, rather than trying to get it directly from the XML.  But, I'm a code-ish guy

Comment: @Flydog57 It's a web server backend. If I was meant to process the data myself, I'd just launch Microsoft Excel :)

Comment: I'm not saying use Excel at all.  The OpenXml Productivity Tool allows you to open an Excel (or other Office .*x file) and look at the XML in a very clean way, or look at code that could be used to generate the XML.  If you open an existing file, you will see how everything is organized.  Then you can write your server tool.  No, never install Excel on a server!

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post and OP has likely moved on, but in case any one else is interested heres what I found.

I came across this problem as well while writing a simple parser to do some XLSX massaging and couldn't find the documentation to indicate the exact way the XML file names map to the sheets defined in `workbook.xml`.

Here's what I discovered:

There seems to be three ways to determine this; I've illustrated 2 below and OP's would be the third.

First, given from what I've seen OP's solution should indeed work and is probably the correct way to do this as the relationship between reference IDs and files are maintained in the `.rels` files. I took a different approach and, in hindsight, I should have used OPs solution but I didn't known exactly how the relationships worked at the time.

---

Given this excerpt from a `xl/workbook.xml` file which is a fragment of an XLSX file generated from Excel where I:

1. Added 3 sheets (with some content so I could tell them apart in the XML files) then saved.
2. Deleted the second sheet then saved again.
3. Moved the new second sheet (was the third originally) in front of the first and resaved for a third time.

```
<sheets>
  <sheet name="Third Sheet" sheetId="3" r:id="rId1"/>
  <sheet name="First Sheet" sheetId="1" r:id="rId2"/>
</sheets>
```

In the extracted XML files the XLSX sheet mapping are listed below based on the content I originally added to the sheets:

```
xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml ---> sheetId="3" Third Sheet r:id="rid1"
xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml ---> sheetId="1" First Sheet r:id="rid2"
```

So from that it looks to be that the sheet names can map as such:

1. The positional index + 1 of the `sheet` element under the `sheets` element in the `xl/workbook.xml` file matches the trailing ID on the sheet filename.
2. The trailing number of the id attribute (`rid1` and `rid3`) matches the trailing ID on the sheet filename.

PSA:

Don't be like me and initially assume the `sheetID` attribute maps to the sheet filename, that is incorrect. Also, use OP's solution as it is more correct and relies on hard references rather than mine which infers the references.

Comment: which OP solution?